# fetch all live ips connected with same wifi or router using socket programming in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I am working in an app for that I need all live ips connected with same wifi or router where my device is connected.

I need this operation in background. I have used [LAN-Scan](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan) but it will take approx 2 to 3 minutes to ping all ips from 0 to 255. I have also used [MMLanScan](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan) but issue is it will perform in main thread and I want to perform it in background.

I am confused and stuck in this functionality any one please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: MMLanScan scans in a background thread using NSOperationQueue without blocking the UI. What exactly is the problem you face?

Comment: I need only live IPs not mac addresses what can I do? @BlackM

Comment: There is an object "Device" with properties ipAddres,mac,hostname. Just use IP. eg. `device.ipAddress`